# Django - Variable is not getting send with POST request

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms, django-views

Hey im using for my django project typescript to get a specific section from a text to my view but it somehow doesnt work and I dont really know why.

Here is my template in which I want the "currentgap" sent to my view after clicking on the submit button. The getSelectionText() method just sets the id 'gap' to a specific string:

```
<form action="editorgapcreate" id=create method="POST">

<script src="../static/textselector.js"></script>

  <div id="app" onmouseup="getSelectionText()">
    This is a test section.
  </div>

  {% csrf_token %}

  <b>Your current selected gap:</b>
  <p id="currentgap"></p>

  <input type="hidden" name="gap" id="currentgap">

  <button type="submit" name="create_gap">Create gap</button>

</form>
```

and here is my view in which I tried calling it:

```
def editorstart(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    gap = request.POST['gap']
    print(gap)
    return render(request, 'editor_start.html')
  else:
    return render(request, 'editor_start.html')
```

The first time using currentgap in my template it displays it correctly but trying to send it to my view with a POST request doesnt work and the print is empty and I dont really know why.

**EDIT:**

My textselector.js:

```
function getSelectionText() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
  }
  else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
document.getElementById('currentgap').innerHTML = text;
return text;
}
```

Comment: I'm no django expert but looks like you need to add your variable to the context.

Comment: you mean setting currentgap to a value?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056263/using-django-view-variables-inside-templates

Comment: But thats not really the problem here, im trying to get a string from my template to my view with an input and not the other way around

Comment: Please show the getSelectionText() function.

Comment: added the getselectiontext() function :)

Comment: But there's nothing here that is populating the value of the hidden input.

Comment: and btw, you can’t have the same value for the id attribute for more than one element in an html page.

Comment: So, you mean I cant use the same id twice like in my example with "currentgap"?

Comment: your hidden input doesn't have a value attached to it, so in your view POST.get('gap') is just a empty string

Comment: As others have pointed out, you have to use unique ids and then add  `document.getElementById('currentgap').value = text;` to your js. This adds value to input.

Comment: alright thanks, giving them two different ids and using .value worked :)