# how to create the correct context in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.2

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
  context = {
    'title' : 'test'

  }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: `context` should be a `dict`; please read about Python `dict` first.

Comment: I just edited the question, please take a look again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Django view variables inside templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056263/using-django-view-variables-inside-templates)

Answer (score 0):

Django's context data are just simple python dictionaries.

So you should define them like this:

```
context = {
    'first_key': first_value,
    'second_key': second_value,
}
```

Edit (as you change the question and error):

You should use tabs, or spaces, not both mixed together...

Comment: I just edited the question, please take a look again

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, when you indent the code, you should use either tabs, or spaces. If you mix both, you will get this error.

Comment: prefer tabs or spaces dude?

Comment: Spaces, as PEP8 recommends, but you can set your editor's setting so that it automatically change tabs to spaces.

Comment: Please also mark the answer as accepted if that solves the issue, or let me know if you have any further issues.