# How do i display my views.py output on a template

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

this is my views.py

```
from django import template
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def print_headlines(request,response_text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response_text, 'lxml')
    headlines = soup.find_all(attrs={"itemprop": "headline"})
    for headline in headlines:
        print(headline.text)
        context = {
            "headline": headline
        }
    return render(request, 'home/maroweb.html', context)


url = 'https://inshorts.com/en/read'
response = requests.get(url)
print_headlines(response.text)
```

then on my webpage i use {{headlines}} to display the results but nothing shows template code

then on my webpage i use {{headlines}} to display the results but nothing shows template code

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
 {{ self.banner_title }}

{% for headline in headline %}

  {{headline}}

  {% endfor %}


 {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

i have added the complete code on the template

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056263/using-django-view-variables-inside-templates

Comment: try {{ headline }} not {{ headlines }}. You are using extra 's' in template

Comment: same outcome ,still doesn't show the results on the webpage

Answer (score 0):

Please use {{headline}} in your webpage because in your context you are passing "headline".
I am seeing that it has many data so you can also use for loop in django template.
like below....

```
  {% for headline in headline %}

  {{headline}}

  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you show your template code.. Please also check you are rendering on right page or not.

Comment: I've added it to the main post

Comment: Can you use context line out of loop and then try.       def print_headlines(request,response_text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response_text, 'lxml')
    headlines = soup.find_all(attrs={"itemprop": "headline"})
    
        context = {
            "headline": headlines
        }
    return render(request, 'home/maroweb.html', context)

Comment: Nothing changed, it's  still the same

Comment: Have you checked data comes from your filter or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django import template
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def print_headlines(request,response_text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response_text, 'lxml')
    headlines = soup.find_all(attrs={"itemprop": "headline"})
    context = {
        "headlines": headlines
    }
    return render(request, 'home/maroweb.html', context)

url = 'https://inshorts.com/en/read'
response = requests.get(url)
print_headlines(response.text)
```

And your template will be:

```
{% for headline in headlines %}
    {{ headline }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It didn't work and views.py isn't even displaying the output on the terminal. I'm getting TypeError: print_headlines() missing. 1 required positional argument : 'response_text'

Comment: @user12075410 are you calling Django views like any other function call? This is not how it works..you will have to setup urlpatterns and mention your `print_headlines` view there to make it work. Please go through Django's documentation one more time. Additionally, you are getting the error because your function `print_headlines` requires two arguments namely, `request` and `response_text` and you are passing only one.

Comment: Okay, i didn't know this. I'll add urlpatterns